# Как вывести названия options в select так, чтобы при повторении название пропускалось

Tags: php, база-данных, условия

Есть таблица commands в ней id, названия команд(title) и названия турниров(tournament). Так вот как сделать select, options с названиями турниров так, чтобы пр  повторении повторное название пропускалось.
Пример

```
$commands = mysqli_query($DB, "SELECT *FROM `commands`");
<Select>
While($command = mysqli_fetch_assoc($commands)) {
echo "<option>" . $commannd["tournament"] . "</option>";
</select>
```

В таблице
Id 1,название команды example, название турнира #1
Id 2, название команды example2, название турнира #2
И т.д.

Так вот как вывести в option все названия турниров, но не выводить повторяющиесяся. То есть если 2 турнира с названием #2 то как не дать компилятор выводить #2 2 раза

Надеюсь понятно объяснил, заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `commands` 
GROUP BY `tournament`
```

Answer (score 0):

Ещё вариант:

`select distinct tournament from commаnds`